# Как переопределить диалог андроид, используя тему Theme.Holo.Light?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Здравствуйте
Интересует вопрос: можно ли изменить цвет горизонтальной полосы между названием и телом диалога (в этой теме она голубая по умолчанию)
Нашел в файле \sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\themes.xml в описании темы Theme.Holo.Light параметр

```
<item name="dialogTitleDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title_holo</item>
```

но переопределить его нет возможности.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для кастомизации лучше всего написать свой кастомный диалог. Вот привожу пример кастомного диалога:

```
public class MDialogs extends Dialog implements
        View.OnClickListener {

private Activity m_Activity;
private Button m_YesButton, m_NoButton;

public MDialogs(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    this.m_Activity = a;
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
            setContentView(R.layout.remove_dialog);
            m_YesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
            m_NoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
            m_YesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            m_NoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnYes:
                   break;
                case R.id.btnNo:
                   break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```